# Page Title displaying in browser html but not google

Tags: joomla, joomla3.4

Google webmaster is telling me that on quite a few websites we have that there are missing page titles. On these pages google has taken the menu item name for the title.

The menu has its page title filled in and is showing correctly in the inspect element on the browser.

One example is we would like the page title to read:
UK Injection Moulding Manufacturers
Again, page title in html shows correctly but google just displays manufacturing as its title.

The joomla version is 3.4.3.

Comment: Examine the HTML source that is being generated, and go from there. Could be any number of reasons that this is happening. Additionally, if the titles were just changed, it takes time for Google to re-crawl your site.

Comment: I have checked the head.php- i have even copied one in from a site that is functioning. I changed the page titles on Friday, I think looking at webmaster that google crawled on Saturday as the webmaster crawl stats show 10 pages for the 15th.

Answer (score 0):

If you use google, often the results are already cached from your previous browsing.
Try to use Tor browser and verify if the page title is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by the incorrect setup of the menu items. What you might be seeing as the title is actually the article title which is a H2.

Edit the Menu Item -> Page Display -> Show PAge Heading -> Yes

and set the: Page Heading to what you desire. I.E. UK Injection Moulding Manufacturers

this will show a H1 now. If you then have duplicate text i.e. the article title you can hide this by editing:

Menu Item -> Options -> Show Title -> No.

Many thanks
Tony

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Header tags were fine and page wasn't cached. Still none the wiser but I have started using the os metta extension which makes it much easier to edit multiple page titles and this now seems to be working.